# Infer new cross-references for a library based on existing cross-references

Tags: excel, openai-api, inference

The Excel file at https://basilwhite.com/mrpbs23.xlsx is the start of an index of library books (think card catalog) for a library of strategic plans.
Each row is a cross-reference "card" in the index that links components between two plans, or "sources." Here's the structure of the data.

- Each Enabling Source in Column A contains Enabling Components, which are in Column B.
- The Enabling Components are described in Column C.
- Making progress on the Enabling Component in Column B as described in Column C progresses the Dependent Component in Column D closer to its end-state.
- Column E describes the Dependent Component in Column D.
- The Dependent Component is contained in its Dependent Source in Column F.

I want to use AI to infer rows of new cross-references and generate a percentage value of the confidence of each inference.
I have URLs for two notable failed attempts to getChatGPT to infer new cross-references between strategic source documents.
https://chat.openai.com/c/5549d3a7-e26c-45e3-9d12-f84fdf2e4e69
https://chat.openai.com/c/77d87a0a-5017-4863-bd0f-292260797a52
The second link includes some Python code to interact with the OpenAI. I tried getting ChatGPT to look at the actual Excel file but no joy. I also watched videos on how to use Python and a ChatGPT API key, but that's way beyond my comprehension.
Please help.

x-posts:
r/excel https://www.reddit.com/r/excel/comments/15iu8wi/infer_new_crossreferences_for_a_library_based_on/
r/ChatGPT https://www.reddit.com/r/ChatGPT/comments/15iucgo/infer_new_crossreferences_for_a_library_based_on/
https://github.com/basilwhite/ivn/issues/
[Infer new cross-references for a library based on existing cross-references](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76841825/infer-new-cross-references-for-a-library-based-on-existing-cross-references)
https://community.openai.com/t/infer-new-cross-references-for-a-library-based-on-existing-cross-references/316566